# Prevent excel formula from updating unless found in xlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that has xlookup formulas for multiple cells. This table pulls info with xlookup from a powerquery table on a different sheet that gets updated daily. I'm trying to have the formula only pull information that is present in the power query and leave all existing information alone.

This is the table where all the formulas are

[image]

This is what I currently have in each column to pull the Date Complete and Exception Comments

```
=IFERROR(IF(XLOOKUP([@[HOST name ]],Output!A:A,Output!D:D,,0)="SUCCESS",XLOOKUP([@[HOST name ]],Output!A:A,Output!B:B,,0),""),"")
```

Comment: Formula are live and as such will always re-calc as the data changes.  You will need vba to do the mining, which then can leave a static value.

Comment: Do you know know I would go about coding that? I've used the Application.Workbookfunction.Vlookup option but thats about it for that type of code.